# Where is WebsitePanel Server pool located on Windows?

Tags: windows, iis

I need to find WebsitePanel Server pool on my PC. I don't know the location of it. Can anyone appoint me to that location. I don't know is it a part of IIS or something elese. Current configuration is Win 8 with IIS 7.5 installed. Than kyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?
Adding a **WebsitePanel server**

- Begin by going to Setup > Servers
- Click Add New Server
- In the server details box, select the server type "WebsitePanel" from
  the dropdown menu.
- Enter the IP/Hostname of your Enterprise server install
- Enter the username and password for the account that has permissions
  to create your users. The account has to be a reseller account with
  permissions to create packages under the top level hosting space your
  customers will be created under.
- Tick SSL if you wish to connect using a SSL connection

  ref:http://docs.whmcs.com/WebsitePanel
  or this one [WebSitePanel:007-Setting ACL for Root Organizational Unit](http://tmitegypt.wordpress.com/category/websitepanel/) ?